# Is $\mathbb{Z}_9^*$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I'm reading "A course in algebra" (2003) by E. B. Vinberg to have a basic understanding on algebra. Now I got a question.

Exercise 4.46. says "Prove that the group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ of invertible elements of the ring
\mathbb{Z} (see Exercise 1.50) is cyclic for $n < 7$ and is not cyclic for $n = 8, 9$."

For $n=9$, the invertible elements (with its inverse) are: $1(1)$, $2(5)$, $4(7)$, $5(2)$, $7(4)$, $8(8)$.

So $\mathbb{Z}_9^*=\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$, it seems this can be generated by either $2$ or $5$?
$$2\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 8\rightarrow 16\equiv 7\rightarrow 14\equiv 5\rightarrow 10\equiv 1\rightarrow 2$$

$$5\rightarrow 25\equiv 7\rightarrow 35\equiv 8\rightarrow 40\equiv 4\rightarrow 20\equiv 2\rightarrow 10\equiv 1\rightarrow 5$$

So $\mathbb{Z}_9^*=\langle 2\rangle =\langle 5\rangle$.

Is this an error or I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah. It's an abelian group of order $6$, so it must be cyclic.

Comment: For a prime $p$, the group $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$ is always cyclic (of order $(p-1)p^{n-1}$). Your calculations are correct btw.

Comment: The $n$ for which $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is cyclic are exactly $n = 2, 4, p^k$, or $2p^k$ for $p$ an odd prime.

Comment: ^That's only true for odd primes.

Comment: @Nishant i don't get it that "an abelian group of order 6 must be cyclic". could you pls give a hint?

Comment: @athos: There are two groups of order six up to isomorphism: $S_{3}$, the permutation group on three letters, and $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, the cyclic group of order $6$. Since $S_{3}$ is nonabelian (this is easy to verify), any abelian group of order $6$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Comment: @Dane wow that's a quite strong result!

Comment: If you think that's strong, wait until you learn about the Sylow Theorems...

Comment: @AWertheim wow... do algebrians study all the isomorphism types of $S_n$?

Comment: @Nishant Sylow theorems are in ch 10.4, i'm heading to it :)

Comment: @athos: Algebraists study many things! Classification of groups up to isomorphism is certainly one of them. I'm not sure what you mean by isomorphism types of $S_{n}$, but I'd be happy to say more if you elaborate. Perhaps this may interest you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups

Comment: @AWertheim Being a layman on math, only knowing Riemann integral, recently I feel the need to get the fundamentals right, so after basic set theory the current reading topic is algebra, more on the basic and general ideas, other than a specific interest. Algebra is quite interesting! Thanks for the lead. Let me digest that and Prof Vinberg's book first. Definitely I'll seek help on MSE if got problems.

Comment: Whether $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is cyclic or not can be rephrased as whether $\lambda(n)=\phi(n)$, where $\lambda(n)$ is the reduced totient function (https://brilliant.org/wiki/carmichaels-lambda-function/). Since $9=3^2$, we have $\lambda(9)=\phi(9)$.